# how to find term statistics of a document by specifying its field value in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch. I need to get the term statistics from documents by specifying a field that contains a certain value. I put following kind of documents to elasticsearch.

```
PUT /twitter/tweet/1
{
    "user" : "ABC",
    "post_date" : "2015-11-25T14:12:12",
    "message" : "this is my first tweet."
}
```

Now I want to get the term statistics of the field "message" of every Document where the "user" field contains value "ABC". I want to do this through Java. First I would like to know how to write the query for this.

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself? These are baby steps and there are tons of tutorials on interwebz.

Comment: I can get the results by specifying a certain value in a field. But I cant get the term statistics of the results. I used termvectors. But it only gives term statistics per document. I cant combine termvectors and the query for taking the term statistics.